# How to post value in the nested json array in angular 5?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, angular5, angular6

I have nested json format being exposed from Web API. Can someone help me in sending the same format data from Angular5

```
{"contractId":1,
 "contractName":"Temp",
 "contractServiceList":[
    {"id":1,
     "serviceId":{"serviceId":1,"serviceName":"Emergency Room"},
     "providerTier":"Tier 1",
     "coinsurance":100.0,
     "copay":10.0,
     "penaltyApplies":"Y",
     "penaltyRule":"Non Emergency ER Use",
     "penaltyType":"Dollar Amount",
     "penaltyValue":300.0,
     "deductibleApplies":"Y"
    }
  ]
}
```

Below is the piece of code, which gives the inner list "contractServiceList" as null. How to subscribe data so that it should get the values inside the inner list

app.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.addForm = this.formBuilder.group({
          contractName: ['', Validators.required],
          serviceName: ['', Validators.required],
          copayAmount: ['', Validators.required],
          coInsurance: ['', Validators.required],
          deductibleApplies: ['', Validators.required],
          penaltyApplies: ['', Validators.required],
          penaltyRule: ['', Validators.required],
          penaltyType: ['', Validators.required],
          penaltyValue: ['', Validators.required],
          deductibleAppliesPenalty: ['', Validators.required]
    });
}
onSubmit() {
    this.contractService.saveContract(this.addForm.value)
    .subscribe( data => {
        alert('Contract created successfully');
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

service.ts

```
 saveContract(contract: Contract) {
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl, contract).pipe(map(res => res.json));
  }
```

app.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="addForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <table>
<thead></thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
   <td>
   <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
      <label for="contractName">Contract Name:</label>
      <input formControlName="contractName" placeholder="Contract Name" class="form-control" name="contractName" id="contractName">
    </div>
   </td>
<td>
 <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
     <h4 style="margin-left:100px;">Penalty Conditions</h4>
    </div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
      <label for="serviceName">Category Of Services:</label>
      <select id ="serviceName" formControlName="serviceName" name="serviceName" class="form-control">
    <option *ngFor="let serv of serviceId" [value]="serv.serviceId">{{serv.serviceName}}</option>
</select>
      </div>
    </td>
<td>
 <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
      <label for="penaltyApplies">Penalty Applies:</label>
       <select id ="penaltyApplies" formControlName="penaltyApplies" name="penaltyApplies" class="form-control">
    <option>--Select--</option>
    <option>Y</option>
    <option>N</option>
</select>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
      <label for="copayAmount">Copay Amount:</label>
      <input formControlName="copayAmount" placeholder="Copay Amount" class="form-control" name="copayAmount" id="copayAmount">
    </div>
    </td>
    <td>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
      <label for="penaltyRule">Penalty Rule:</label>
       <select id ="penaltyRule" formControlName="penaltyRule" name="penaltyRule" class="form-control">
    <option>--Select--</option>
    <option>Non Emergency ER Use</option>
</select>
      </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
      <label for="deductibleApplies">Deductible Applies:</label>
        <select id ="deductibleApplies" formControlName="deductibleApplies" name="deductibleApplies" class="form-control">
    <option>--Select--</option>
    <option>Y</option>
    <option>N</option>
</select></div>
    </td>
    <td>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
      <label for="penaltyType">Penalty Type:</label>
      <select id ="penaltyType" name="penaltyType" formControlName="penaltyType" class="form-control">
    <option>--Select--</option>
    <option>Coinsurance</option>
    <option>Dollar Amount</option>
</select></div>
    </td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meenal, ContractServiceList is an Array, so you must use an ArrayForm. I suggested always make a function to return a form

```
export class TabGroupBasicExample implements OnInit {
  addForm:FormGroup;

  //this function make easier access to the Form array
  get contractList() {
     return this.addForm.get('contractServiceList') as FormArray;
  }
  constructor(private formBuilder:FormBuilder){}

  //this function return a FormGroup empty or filled with the data
  createForm(data:any):FormGroup
  {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      contractId: [data? data.contractId:'',Validators.required],
      serviceName: [data? data.serviceName:''], 
      //to return the array we use a function that return an array of FormGroup
      contractServiceList:this.formBuilder.array(
             this.createContractService(data?data.contractServiceList:null)
              )
      });
  }

  //see that createContractService return an array of FormGroup
  createContractService(data:any[]|null):FormGroup[]
  {
        //if receive a data array, for each item in array return 
        //a fromGroup with the value    
    return data?
      data.map(x=>{
        let group=this.formBuilder.group({
          copayAmount: [x.copayAmount, Validators.required],
          coInsurance: [x.coInsurance, Validators.required],
          deductibleApplies: [x.deductibleApplies, Validators.required],
          penaltyApplies: [x.penaltyApplies, Validators.required],
          penaltyRule: [x.penaltyRule, Validators.required],
          penaltyType: [x.penaltyType, Validators.required],
          penaltyValue: [x.penaltyValue, Validators.required],
          deductibleAppliesPenalty: [x.deductibleAppliesPenalty, Validators.required]
            });
        return group;
      }):
      [this.formBuilder.group(
        {
          copayAmount: ['', Validators.required],
          coInsurance: ['', Validators.required],
          deductibleApplies: ['', Validators.required],
          penaltyApplies: ['', Validators.required],
          penaltyRule: ['', Validators.required],
          penaltyType: ['', Validators.required],
          penaltyValue: ['', Validators.required],
          deductibleAppliesPenalty: ['', Validators.required]
        })]
  }


  ngOnInit()
  {
    this.addForm=this.createForm(null)
    }
}
```

**Update** 
If you has an object like

```
let contrat={
  "contractId": "2",
  "serviceName": "qqqq",
  "contractServiceList": [
    {
      "copayAmount": "12",
      "coInsurance": "22553",
      "deductibleApplies": "12",
      "penaltyApplies": "",
      "penaltyRule": "",
      "penaltyType": "1",
      "penaltyValue": "",
      "deductibleAppliesPenalty": "2"
    }
  ]
}
```

You can make

```
this.addForm=this.createForm(contract)
```

And you get the values ready for update.

You .html must take account you're working with a formArray

```
    <form *ngIf="addForm" [formGroup]="addForm" >
      <!--or your fileds not in array-->
       <input formControlName="contractId"/>
       <input formControlName="serviceName">
      <!--Your form Array name---->
    <div formArrayName="contractServiceList">
    <!--a div *ngFor over addForm.get('contractServiceList').controls 
     don't forget formGroupName="i"-->
    <div *ngFor="let items of contractList.controls; let i=index" 
            [formGroupName]="i">

         <!--al your controls of the array here-->
       <input formControlName="copayAmount"/>
       <input formControlName="coInsurance"/>
       ....
    </div>
</div>
<!--just for check -->
<pre>{{addForm?.value |json}}</pre>
```

Well you want to make a table, Change the .html

**Update 2**
If we want to validate the formArray itself we can build a custom validator. Well I like make a custom validator as a function in the own component. For Custom validators more generally -user in several component- see https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators

So, we can add in the component.ts

```
   arrayValidator(){

    return (control: FormArray) => {
      console.log(control.value);
      //using value, you return an object if error or null
      return null;
    }
  }
```

And change when create the array as

```
  contractServiceList:this.formBuilder.array(
         this.createContractService(data?data.contractServiceList:null),
         this.arrayValidator()
          )
```

Comment: How about the service.ts, is that the correct way of posting data?

Comment: Well. I don't know about your API. It's strange that return a result.json, but I don't know. (I supouse you "http" is HttpClient https://angular.io/guide/http (not the old and deprecated http)

Comment: Appreciate your effort on this but my bad, still not clear with what we are achieving. It would be good if you explain what you suggested in detail since I am very new to Angular. this.addForm=this.createForm(null) - Will this always createForm as null. Please share exact code for HTML based on json above.

Comment: @Meenal, I've make a stackblizt https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-161pb9-pxor9v?file=app%2Ftab-group-basic-example.ts The idea is that, when you read one contract (using a httpClient.get("url...").subscribe(res=>..) you can format a form width the data readed, so you can update. Normally the operations New and Update, are made in an uniq component. I update my answer

Comment: Awesome!! It worked for me. A big thanks to you but just one more help. I want to add a search functionality on the same form itself so once the search button is clicked the values will automatically populate in the same html and Save btn will be hidden. So, can I have another form in the same component.ts and in html will do *ngIf="searchForm" so that based on form condition, respective forms will be displayed. Please suggest, else I'll go with another new page for Search functionality.

Comment: Hey Eliseo: How can we add Form validations on contractServiceList. From your code, I could see Required validation in .ts file but how can we get them in .html I am able to get validation on contractName which is outside the inner list.
       [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.contractName.errors }">
    <div *ngIf="submitted && f.contractName.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                            <div *ngIf="f.contractName.errors.required">Contract Name is required</div>

Comment: you must use .. && items.get('copayAmount').errors -well I'm use "items as variable of the *ngFor. If you want to create a full validator over the array you can do too (It's not very good because can retarded the page): Update the stackblitz and the response

Comment: Your code will always show Required message. I have used boolean in .ts and on OnSubmit() method, making boolean=true so that I can check on contractId field and then populate error message.<input .... name="copay" id="copay" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && items.get('copay').errors }"><div *ngIf="submitted && items.get('copay').errors" class="invalid-feedback"><div *ngIf="items.get('copay').errors" required>Copay is required</div></div> This is the code of html. Could you please verify if Iam doing something wrong here since ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'errors' of undefined

Comment: @Meenal, is get('copayAmount').errors, and not if you enter any value in the input the "required" disapear.TIP:you can write "items.get('copayAmount')?.errors -see the "?"- to avoid error if not found the control-

Comment: Hey Eliseo, An extension to this thread. I want to cache the POST response and show it in html. Any idea how can we do that. E.g. I am getting {
  "contractId": 44,
  "contractName": "BOND",
  "contractServiceList": [
    {
      "id": 44,
      "serviceId": 1,
      "providerTier": null,
      "coinsurance": 35,.....]}
 & I want the contractId which is coming from server (auto-generated) so instead of calling http.get call, I will store this info. in cache and can fetch this to show up in html. Lemme know if any other simple way. Please suggest!!